# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1000, 1), indices imply (1000, 2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

How do I fix this error, the code is given below. I have defined X to be the two columns of a dataframe I need, and Y to be the target column/output. I am trying to implement a gradient descent algorithm to predict the optimum weights 'w'. The error is in the line 'Y_hat=predict_Y(b,w,X)'. Note: X is a dataframe of size (1000,2), but only (1000,1) is being passed to the function.

```
import random
X=data[['dr_rr','qr_rr']]
Y=data['buyer_rating']
def initialize(dim):
    np.random.seed(seed=42)
    random.seed(42)
    b=random.random()
    w=np.random.rand(dim)
    return b,w
b,w=initialize(2)
print("Bias",b,"weights:",w)
def predict_Y(b,w,X):
    return b + np.matmul(X,np.transpose(w))
b, w=initialize(2)
Y_hat=predict_Y(b,w,X)
Y_hat[0:10]
```

the error is

```
Bias 0.6394267984578837 weights: [0.37454012 0.95071431]
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1677                 blocks = [
-> 1678                     make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
   1679                 ]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype, fastpath)
   3266 
-> 3267     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   3268 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    127                 "Wrong number of items passed {val}, placement implies "
--> 128                 "{mgr}".format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs))
    129             )

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-8c3349b8b93a> in <module>
      2     return b + np.matmul(X,np.transpose(w))
      3 b, w=initialize(2)
----> 4 Y_hat=predict_Y(b,w,X)
      5 Y_hat[0:10]

<ipython-input-24-8c3349b8b93a> in predict_Y(b, w, X)
      1 def predict_Y(b,w,X):
----> 2     return b + np.matmul(X,np.transpose(w))
      3 b, w=initialize(2)
      4 Y_hat=predict_Y(b,w,X)
      5 Y_hat[0:10]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array_wrap__(self, result, context)
   1997     def __array_wrap__(self, result, context=None):
   1998         d = self._construct_axes_dict(self._AXIS_ORDERS, copy=False)
-> 1999         return self._constructor(result, **d).__finalize__(self)
   2000 
   2001     # ideally we would define this to avoid the getattr checks, but

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    438                 mgr = init_dict({data.name: data}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    439             else:
--> 440                 mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    441 
    442         # For data is list-like, or Iterable (will consume into list)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    211         block_values = [values]
    212 
--> 213     return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
    214 
    215 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1686         blocks = [getattr(b, "values", b) for b in blocks]
   1687         tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
-> 1688         construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
   1689 
   1690 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   1717         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
   1718     raise ValueError(
-> 1719         "Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(passed, implied)
   1720     )
   1721 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1000, 1), indices imply (1000, 2)
```

Comment: I think your ```X=data[['dr_rr','qr_rr']]``` may be the culprit since it is currently a n by n matrix. Double brackets is a way to code matrices, arrays use single brackets.

Comment: I ran your code on my machine with the following random sample data. It ran without error.  It may be an error in your data.  

Try adding print(data.head()) to inspect your data.  

Try running on a small subset of rows like this:
X = data[['dr_rr','qr_rr']][0:10]
Y = data['buyer_rating'][0:10]

Try running with this sample data:

Comment: I ran your code on my machine with the following random sample data. It ran without error.  It may be an error in your data.  Here are 3 quick things you can do to confirm it is your data.

1. 
Add  to inspect your data.  Anything suspicious?  If not, running on a small subset of rows like this:
from_row, to_row = 0, 10
print(data[from_row:to_row]) 
X = data[['dr_rr','qr_rr']][from_row:to_row]
Y = data['buyer_rating'][from_row:to_row]

2.
Try running with sample data:
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3), columns=['dr_rr', 'qr_rr', 'buyer_rating'])